# How can we access multiple elements with Arrayfun in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, cuda, parallel-processing, gpu

Could anyone help me to access multiple elements of an array (xGrid and yGrid here) from inside a function (fun.m). Performance is my critical point. Here is the function (that is called):

```
function count = fun(x0,y0,maxIter)
z0 = complex(x0,y0);
z = z0;
count = 1;
while count <= maxIter && (real(z)*real(z) + imag(z)*imag(z)) <= 4
    count = count + 1;
    z = z*z + z0;
end
count = log(count);
```

And the Main:

```
x = parallel.gpu.GPUArray.linspace( xlim(1), xlim(2), gridSize );
y = parallel.gpu.GPUArray.linspace( ylim(1), ylim(2), gridSize );
[xGrid,yGrid] = meshgrid( x, y );
count = arrayfun(@fun,xGrid, yGrid, maxIter);
```

I know I only get access to x0 and y0 (inside fun/arrayfun, when i=1, j=1), but can I also access x1, x2... and y1, y2.. at that same position (i=1 and j=1) and without passing them in parameters?

Comment: Curious if you've tried Jacket?  In most benchmarks I've seen, it is at least 10X faster than using GPUArrays.  I'm biased cause I work on Jacket, but I'm also curious if you've done the benchmarking yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(sorry for the earlier answer, I misread the question)

If you want to access other elements of xGrid and yGrid from inside fun, why not pass xGrid, yGrid into the function? Matlab uses [copy-on-write](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/152-can-matlab-pass-by-reference), so passing them in shouldn't impact the efficiency of the code unless you write to them.

Comment: But how can I do that using Arrayun? Arrayfun take/process only one-by-one elements from arrays. should I use structures instead of arrays then? -Thanks

Comment: You can use an anonymous function to specify some additional arguments:
`count = arrayfun(@(x, y)fun(x, y, maxIter, xGrid, yGrid), xGrid, yGrid);`
this would do the same as your program does now, but the 4th and 5th arguments to `fun` would be the xGrid and yGrid matrices.

Comment: Thanks that is what I was looking for. One last thing please. Can I be sure that there are no copies made of xGrid and yGrid inside @fun? I am very limited in memory.

Comment: There will be no copies unless you assign to them (e.g. xGrid(3, 2) = 10).